# How to filter neomodel nodes by their attributes after traversal?

Tags: python, database, neo4j, neomodel

I have the following neo4j models with a Document and Text relationship, where multiple texts are linked to a document :

```py
class Document(StructuredNode):
    """Document Neo4J model for documents"""
    document_id = IntegerProperty(required = True)


class Text(StructuredNode):
    """Text model for managing texts"""

    # Inherent text properties
    text_id = IntegerProperty(required = True)
    text = StringProperty(required = True)

    document = RelationshipTo('Document', "PARENT")
```

In order to fetch ALL the Text objects linked with a specific document, I am using traversal as follows :

```py
def get_all_texts_by_document_id(document_id):
    document = Document.nodes.get_or_none(document_id = document_id)
    definition = dict(node_class = Text, direction = EITHER, relation_type = "PARENT", model = None)
    document_to_text_traversal = Traversal(document, Text.__label__, definition)
    texts = document_to_text_traversal.all()
    print(f"Returning {len(texts)} texts for document_id {document_id}")
    return texts
```

I want to fetch a text with specific text ID and currently I am iterating with an if condition over the list of all the texts received using the above function.

Is there an inbuilt method / better way to filter on the basis of text_id once the traversal is done ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to filter nodes after traversal with neomodel.

However, if you do not have to use `Traversal` objects, you could use something like this:

- add the relationship from Text to Document by adding this line to your `Document` class:

  ```
  texts = RelationshipFrom('Text', "PARENT")
  ```
- Follow the PARENT relationship and filter on the end nodes:

  ```
  document = Document.nodes.get_or_none(document_id=1)
  if document:
      texts = document.texts.filter(text_id=1)
      print(texts.all())
  ```